# Why ls command combined with xargs and cp move only 10 files?

Tags: shell, copy, xargs

I have a command that copies file from one dir to another

```
FILE_COLLECTOR_PATH="/var/www/";
FILE_BACKUP_PATH='/home/'
ls  $FILE_COLLECTOR_PATH | head -${1} |  xargs -i basename {} | xargs -t -i cp $FILE_COLLECTOR_PATH{} "${FILE_BACKUP_PATH}{}-`date +%F%H%M%S%N`"
```

I loop it in a shell script like,

```
#!/bin/sh
SLEEP=120
FILE_COLLECTOR_PATH="/var/www/";
FILE_BACKUP_PATH='/home/'
while true
do
ls  $FILE_COLLECTOR_PATH | head -${1} |  xargs -i basename {} | xargs -t -i cp $FILE_COLLECTOR_PATH{} "${FILE_BACKUP_PATH}{}-`date   +%F%H%M%S%N`"
 sleep ${SLEEP}
done
```

But it seems to move only 10 files and not all files in the dir, Why? It should suppose to move all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, [don't try to parse the output of `ls` in a script](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  You can end up with many different types of subtle problems.  There is almost always a better tool for the job.  Many times, this tool is [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).  For example, to generate a list of all of the files in a directory and do something to each of them, you would do something like this:

```
find <search directory> -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0i basename {} ...
```

The `-print0` and `-0` arguments allow `find` and `xargs` to communicate filenames in a way that handles special characters (like spaces) correctly.

The `find` command has other options that you may find useful in a backup script (which is what it appears you are building).  Options like `-mmin` and `-newer` will enable you to only back up files that have changed since the last iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing

```
ls -1
```

instead of just `ls`, because `ls` by default don't displays files on a newline (`tail` expect newlines) for each files when `ls -1` does.